# ¿Cómo pasar los datos de un archivo .txt a una tabla de datos usando python?

Tags: python

En el archivo .txt tengo tres columnas, en la primera está el nombre, en la segunda la coordenada en x y la tercera la coordenada en y.
Necesito pasar esos datos a una tabla.
Agradecería mucho su respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.-Puedes usar `pd.read_csv(path, sep = "/")` donde en path pones la ruta de tu archivo y en sep, el separador con el que difernecias cada columna, si es un csv por defecto es la coma, pero en tu teexto plano, podria ser cualquier caracter.

2.-Después te recomiendo uses `df.head()` para que te asegures que estas leyendo correctamente tu archivo

3.- Finalmente usa `pd.to_excel(path, sheet= 'Nombre')` donde en path ahora pondras la ruta del archivo inclutendo al final su nombre y extencion, p.e. Nombre.xlsx. Y en Sheet le daras un nombre a la hoja donde se guardara tu contenido.

Espero te sirva. Sin más detalles de lo que tienes no podemos ayudarte mucho más

¡Saludos!